# Are Muslims discouraged from having physical relations with their wives during the last 10 nights of Ramadan?

Tags: nikah, ramadan, intercourse

Or even during the odd nights during the last ashra of Ramadan? I am not implying that it may be haraam, just want to know if it is discouraged or disliked.

Would request that you furnish your answers from the Qur'an and the Sunnah of the Messenger (SAWS).

Comment: Per (2:187) there is no prohibition, except of course for the Mu'takifeen - people in the I’tikaf - which is in the last ten days of Ramadan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Verse 187 Surat al Baqara God allows the physical relations in the whole of Ramadan.

> [2:187] *It has been made lawful for you to go to your wives during the
> nights of the fast days. They are as a garment to you and you are as a
> garment to them.*
>
> Though Allah knew that you were secretly dishonest to
> yourselves, He has pardoned your guilt and forgiven you. NOW you are
> permitted to have intercourse with your wives and enjoy what Allah has
> made lawful for you. You are also pemitted to eat and drink during the
> nights of the Fast months. until you can discern the white streak of
> dawn from the blackness of night. Then (abstain from all these things
> and) complete your fast till night-fall.
>
> *But you should not have
> intercourse with your wives while you confine yourselves to mosques.*
>
> These are the bounds set by Allah; so do nut go near them. In this way
> Allah makes His Commands clear to mankind. It is expected that they
> will guard themselves against wrong ways.

So having a sexual relation with your wife/husband during the nights is allowed generally. But if you have the Niyya to do I'tikaf in a mosque it would be prohibited!

And as we find in Sahih Muslim according to um almu'minyn A'icha (may allah be pleased with her) the Prophet (peace be upon him) quit his wifes during these nights that means he didn't have such relation at these nights. As we are asked to follow his sunna it is preferable to do the same. But as mentioned if you can't hold on it is allowed to have physical relationship and it is no sin at all.